# Updating LiveActivities with Push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, push-notification, activitykit

I am trying to update the live activities with push notifications and I use the two methods one to start the live activity and the other to update the live activity which are as follows:

```
func startActivity(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        print("startActivity() is running")
        let attributes = PizzaDeliveryAttributes(numberOfPizzas: 2, totalAmount: "420", orderNumber: "359")

        let future = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 35, to: Date())!.addingTimeInterval(40)
        let date = Date.now...future

        let initialContentState = PizzaDeliveryAttributes.ContentState(driverName: "Bill James", deliveryTimer:date)

        let activityContent = ActivityContent(state: initialContentState, staleDate: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 30, to: Date())!)

        do {
            self.deliveryActivity = try Activity.request(attributes: attributes, content: activityContent, pushType: .token)
            print("Requested a pizza delivery Live Activity \(String(describing: self.deliveryActivity?.id)).")

            Task {
                for await data in self.deliveryActivity!.pushTokenUpdates {
                    let myToken = data.map {String(format: "%02x", $0)}.joined()
                    print("Token printed: \(myToken)")
                    completion(myToken)
                }
            }

        } catch (let error) {
            print("Error requesting pizza delivery Live Activity \(error.localizedDescription).")
        }
    }

    func updatePizzaDeliveryStatus(minutes: String, seconds: String) async {
        var future = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: (Int(minutes) ?? 0), to: Date())!
        future = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: (Int(seconds) ?? 0), to: future)!
        let date = Date.now...future
        let updatedDeliveryStatus = PizzaDeliveryAttributes.PizzaDeliveryStatus(driverName: "Anne Johnson", deliveryTimer: date)
        let alertConfiguration = AlertConfiguration(title: "Delivery update", body: "Your pizza order will arrive in 25 minutes.", sound: .default)
        let updatedContent = ActivityContent(state: updatedDeliveryStatus, staleDate: nil)

        do {
            try await self.deliveryActivity?.update(updatedContent, alertConfiguration: alertConfiguration)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to update Live Activity: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

I am able to generate pushTokens on every new live activity started and also send the curl command through to update the live activity which I will provide below. I expect the dynamic content of the attributes to update, but nothing happens when the push goes through.

```
curl -v \
--header "apns-topic:<Bundle-Id>.push-type.liveactivity" \
--header "apns-push-type:liveactivity" \
--header "authorization: bearer $AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN" \
--data \
'{"aps": {
   "timestamp":1663300480,
   "event": "update",
   "content-state": {
      "driverName": "Tony Stark",
      "deliveryTimer": {
        "start": 1663300480,       
        "end": 1663301480         
    }
   },
   "alert": {
      "title": "Race Update",
      "body": "Tony Stark is now leading the race!"
   }
}}' \
--http2 \
https://${APNS_HOST_NAME}/3/device/$DEVICE_TOKEN
```

And this is what content state in the attributes look like:

```
 public struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
            var driverName: String
            var deliveryTimer: ClosedRange<Date>
        }
```

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same  thing , One aside question , Should we use bundle id of the app or the live extension as the apns-token ? Also what is apns-push-type?

Comment: As far as I know you should be using the bundle id of the app and not the extension.
the apis-push-type is liveactivities as we are setting the type in the header as follows: --header "apns-push-type:liveactivity". If this does not answer your second question, can you elaborate more on it?

Comment: thanks, but when i set the device token to the activity's push token generated from **pushTokenUpdates** in the curl , i got **DeviceTokenNotForTopic** while i set the app bundle as apns-topic

Comment: I tried adding targets bundle as apns topic and I got **DeviceTokenNotForTopic**. goes through fine with app bundle id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your curl, if you're getting a status code `200` response, then the push notifications are making it to the device.

Assuming you're getting a 200, I can see it being two things.

1. Issue with stale timestamps
2. Issue with `ContentState` serializability

#### Timestamp

Your timestamp needs to be updated **each time** you send a push (can't send 2 pushes with the same timestamp). And the time has to be current. You can get that [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/).

#### ContentState

iOS is using codable to deserialize the push notification `content-state` into the struct `ContentState`. For this to work, the keys must match **exactly** for both. (I know this ContentState is from their example, but they use a [simpler one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/updating-and-ending-your-live-activity-with-activitykit-push-notifications) for the push example)

ClosedRange [is codable](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0239-codable-range.md), but I don't know what the keys are (possibly not `start` and `end`).

Try putting only primitive types in your ContentState and see if that fixes it. If so, you can investigate the codability of ClosedRange. Let me know how that goes!

```json
   "content-state": {
      "driverName": "Tony Stark",
      "deliveryStartInt": 1663300480,
      "deliveryEndInt": 1663301480,   
    }
   },
```

```
 public struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
            var driverName: String
            var deliveryStartInt: Int
            var deliveryEndInt: Int
        }
```

Comment: I made it more simpler and changed the second variable in the content state as 
estimatedDelivery: String and made changes accordingly to start and update methods. Unfortunately, it still does not work for me. 

Ps: I do get 200 response.

Comment: Hello, I was able to figure it out! I have provided the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Great! I updated the answer to cover those cases. Was your original deliveryTimer serializing correctly?

Comment: I have a feeling i was messing up somewhere with the closed range, what I did was change the second dynamic variable to a simple string. Either ways, I will check the first content state with the close range and give you and update!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out.

What I did not realise is the timestamp key in the apns payload, i.e;

```
"timestamp":1663300480
```

Needs to be updated every time you send a payload. You can get the latest time stamps from [here](https://www.epochconverter.com). Hope this helps!